# PayuMoney test card details

Tags: payumoney, payu

I am trying to integrate the PayuMoney payment gateway in my application but test cards are not working.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Did you solved it? I am also facing the same error.

Answer (score 10):

PayU offers the following test credentials and it works for me:

Card Type:  **Master**

Card Name:   **Test**

Card Number:   **5123456789012346**

Expiry Date:   **05/25**

CVV:   **123**

OTP :   **123456**

Answer (score 2):

Card Type: VISA

Card 1:- Debit/Credit Card

Card Number: 4854 4601 9876 5435

Expiry Date: 05/21

CVV: 123

OTP : 123456 for Success    &     000000 (6 times-0) for Failure

---

Card Type: Master

Card 2:- Debit/Credit Card (recurring payments)

Card Number: 5123 4567 8901 2346

Expiry Date: 05/21

CVV: 123

OTP : 123456 for Success    &     000000 (6 times-0) for Failure

Answer (score 0):

**Testing:**

You can use the following PayU India test card for testing:

[image]